# Why is Perl telling me that my array is undeclared when I have already declared it?

Tags: perl

I have an input file that looks like this:

```
AC_000044.1_a_bothflanks_2kb_polyA.4    AAGTATAATAAAAAAAAAAAAGAAA   25  25  69646
    AC_000044.1_aa_bothflanks_2kb_polyA.5   AAGTATAATAAAAAAAAATAATTAAAAAAAAAAAAAATAAAAAATAAAATAAAATAAAAATAAAAA  66  91  69644
    AC_000044.1_ab_bothflanks_2kb_polyA.5   TATAATAAAAAAAAAAACATTAAAAATAAAAAATAAAAAATAAAAA  46  137 69647
    AC_000044.1_ac_bothflanks_2kb_polyA.3   TATAATTAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA 27  164 69642
```

5 pieces of information seperated by tabs. I want to take each number in the 5th tab and compare it to every number in the 4th tab, if it is less than or equal to that number that I would like it to return the data in the first tab.

Here is my code:

```
#! /usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;
use Cwd;

my $tab_input = $ARGV[0];
my $output = 'output.txt';
my (@trans_id, @seq, @length, @cum_length, @coord);

open (my $INPUT, "<$tab_input") or die  "unable to open $tab_input\n";
open (my $OUTPUT, ">$output") or die  "unable to open $output\n";

while (<$INPUT>) {

    my @tabfile =split ("\t+",$_);
    push @trans_id, $tabfile[0];
    push @seq, $tab_file[1];
    push @length, $tab_file[2];
    push @cum_length, $tab_file[3];
    push @coord, $tab_file[4];

    for (@tabfile)  {
        if {$tabfile[3] < $tabfile [4]) {
            print "$tabfile[0]\n" > $output;

    }

}

close $output;
close $tab_input;
print "Tab file parsing complete.\n";
```

However, I get errors at line 22 (the if statement) saying that $coord and %cum_length requires explicit package name. I have already delcared the arrays at the top of the code. And why is it returning a % 'hash' symbol in the error code when I am only using arrays. Any ideas?

Comment: You have a wrong bracket. You have `if { ... ) {` with an open curly `{` where you need an open parenthesis `(`, and you're missing the closing curly `}` for the `if` block. And `close $output` tries to close the filename. Your handle is called `$OUTPUT`. All-caps variable names are a bad choice. Name the filehandles `$fh`, `$fh_in`, `$fh_out` or just `$in` and `$out`, but not like something that sounds like a constant. Same for the other `close`.

Comment: `print "$tabfile[0]\n" > $output;` I guess you mean `print $OUTPUT "$tabfile[0]\n"`

Comment: Thanks for the reponse, I've corrected the mistake and that error disappears. I now have another error "Use of uninitialised value in numeric le (<=) at line 22 (the if statement line). So it doesn't like my less than/equal to statement, do you know why?

Comment: @zen_27 I don't think your file is *tab separated* properly. Try using `\s+` instead of `\t+` or only `split` to ignore *leading* and *trailing* spaces.

Comment: @zen_27: If you have a new problem, then it's best to write a new question for it.

Comment: The `for` loop is of no use except for repeating the `if` condition N times where N=`scalar(@tabfile)`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The errors that you describe aren't generated by that code. Here's a list of the problems that I can see

- You have declared `@tabfile` but are using `@tab_file`
- Your statement `if {$tabfile[3] < $tabfile [4]) {` has an opening brace instead of an opening parenthesis
- Your statement `print "$tabfile[0]\n" > $output` should be

  ```
  print $OUTPUT "$tabfile[0]\n";
  ```
- The same statement is missing a closing brace
- `close` requires a *file handle* parameter, not a file name, so your statements `close $output` and `close $tab_input` should be `close $OUTPUT` and `close $INPUT` respectively.

I think it should look more like this

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings 'all';

open my $out_fh, '>', 'output.txt' or die $!;

while ( <> ) {

    my @fields = split;

    print $out_fh "$fields[0]\n" if $fields[3] < $fields [4];
}

print "Tab file parsing complete.\n";
```

Comment: @simbabque: Thank you. I didn't expect there to be quite so many issues!

Comment: Thankyou for your reply! Apolagies for the silly errors. I am using your open statement for the output file, but it doesn't like it. I get an error saying that: String found where operator expected at line10... near $fh_out '>'"

Comment: @zen_27: It looks like you're missing a comma